# best database for write 1 million rows per second in a single node

Tags: database

We have a system that generates 1 million data per second.

we have 1 server and should keep data for 1 week (after 1 week we remove older data)

Each row has a timestamp field, id field and some other fields.

We don't have complex analytic queries, what we want is the database that can handle loading this amount of data and then we can retrieve this data by filtering time and Id (or one or two other columns) from it.

What is the best choice for our case ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have high velocity, I suggest to save your data in Non Relational Database, I pick as an example MongoDB and Cassandra.  You can also merge to an no database solution, you can for example save your data in csv files and use a big data solution (Apache Spark, Hadoop, Hive, Pig, ..) to manage it.

Comment: We test both Mongo and Cassandra in our server and we can not handle 1 million per second write... for Cassandra we test SSTableLoader and  we can handle 300-400k write per second(using multi thread java driver).
for Mongo we can write 150k per second (using multi thread c++ driver)

Comment: then use a non database solution

Comment: We want random access to our data . if we save raw data we should handle random access by hand and it seems it is not easy. so if we can not find suitable database solution we may use this solution.

Comment: Apache Spark support random access to data. If you find this helpful, please upvote and mark as answer

Comment: I am familiar with Apache Spark.
in theory your idea is true... but think we have 1 million per second data... suppose we create a CSV file for each minute.
after that, if we want to find data with id x, time y and other filed z. what CSV file we should load into Spark ?

Comment: you can save all your data in one csv file, this is the best solution. But there is also some alternatives, you can create an RDD or Dataframe from each file then join them all, your data will be treated as one dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153141/discussion-between-mehdi-ben-hamida-and-hosein-ey).

Comment: So if we want find a record what we should do ?
for time x , id y. you say we should load all data into memory for find this record and I think this is not good solution

Comment: Apache spark doesn't load data in memory, Spark create an RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) from data and process on it.